# How do i add a shortcut to print a variable to stdout?

Tags: vim

While coding, i want to select a variable and automatically add a print statement like below by using a custom shortcut:

```
foo = 5
bar = foo * 5
```

If i place my cursor on bar and use this shortcut, i want the output to change to:

```
foo = 5
bar = foo * 5
p "bar = #{bar}"
```

Can anyone help me in adding this shortcut to my vimrc based on the filetype (ruby, python, java etc)?

Answer (score 1):

*snippets* are like the built-in `:abbreviate` on steroids, usually with parameter insertions, mirroring, and multiple stops inside them. One of the first, very famous (and still widely used) Vim plugins is [snipMate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540) (inspired by the *TextMate* editor); unfortunately, it's not maintained any more; though there is [a fork](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate). A modern alternative (that requires Python though) is [UltiSnips](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2715). There are more, see [this list on the Vim Tips Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Category%3aAutomated_Text_Insertion).

There are three things to evaluate: First, the features of the snippet engine itself, second, the quality and breadth of snippets provided by the author or others; third, how easy it is to add new snippets.

Answer (score 1):

```
function Print(p)
    let tmp = a:p.' "'.expand("<cword>").' = #{'.expand("<cword>").'}"'
    call append(line('.'), tmp)
endfunction

autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.py nmap <Leader>x :call Print("print")<CR>
```